# Joomla 3.0 & Chronoforms load db based on cf_user_id

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, chronoforms

I have created a form using chronoforms v4 in joomla 3 and have created a table associated with the form. I am now trying to load the fields from gws_chronoforms_data_gateway_registration based on matching the db record cf_user_id to the current users id.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Have you read all the documentation or posted a comment on the developer forum?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve data from the database table via a ChronoForm with a "DB Record Loader" action in the "On Load" event. Add a WHERE statement under the Advanced tab with cf_id = whatever is relevant.

Add a Custom Code action to display the results like this:

```
<?php
  echo "<div>" . $form->data['fieldname'] . "</div>";
?>
```

There's no need to add any form elements.

See the tutorial at http://www.chronoengine.com/faqs/tutorials/v4-tutorials/162-cfv4dbrecordloader.html for more details.